# Error: ORA-00900 Invalid SQLStatement but statement still works as intended

Tags: java, sql, oracle, error-handling

I created a GUI that can alter and retrieve data from a database. However, some buttons throw a SQLException even though the task was done. (For example, it would give me an error but still insert correctly into the database.

Here is my code:

```
String sqlUser = e.getActionCommand();
String sql;
PreparedStatement stmt;
try{
    if(sqlUser.equals("Save Record"))
                {
                    ResultSet rs;
                    sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (name, ID, result, date, date2) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    stmt.setString(1, textField.getText());
                    stmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText()));
                    stmt.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
                    stmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    stmt.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    updateUI(rs);
                    con.commit();
                }
    else if(sqlUser.equals("Save Update"))
                {
                    ResultSet rs;
                    sql = "UPDATE table_name SET result = ? , date = ?, date2 = ? WHERE name = ? AND ID = ?";
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    stmt.setString(4, textField.getText());
                    stmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText()));
                    stmt.setString(1, textField_2.getText());
                    stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    updateUI(rs);
                    con.commit();
                }
} catch (SQLException err)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,err.getMessage());
}
```

The updateUI method is as follows:

```
public void updateUI(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            String strCDate = dateFormat.format(rs.getDate("date"));
            String strLADate = dateFormat.format(rs.getDate("date2"));

            textField.setText(rs.getString("name"));
            textField_1.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID")));
            textField_2.setText(rs.getString("result"));
            lblCalculationDate.setText("Date: " + strCDate);
            lblLastAccessDate.setText("Date2: " + strLADate);
        }
        catch(SQLException err)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,err.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The DateFormat is this (dont think it matters too much):

```
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Why are you using executeQuery rather than execute? What is the resultSet supposed to contain?

Comment: @alexPoole Is there a difference between executeQuery and execute? Because I've been using just executeQuery and was not aware there was an execute statement. The result set contains one row of data in these cases. (name, id , result, date, and date2) EDIT: I realized why i used executeQuery -- bc it returns a Result set that I could use in order to update the GUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove `con.commit();` as the DB connection by default is autocommit.
- You can use `commit()` only when you set
  `con.setAutoCommit(false);`
- The insertion execution doesn't return a resultSet so remove `rs = stmt.executeQuery();` and instead change the updateUI method to accept two dates a paramters

Full New Code:

```
    String sqlUser = e.getActionCommand();
    String sql;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    try{
        int id = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(sqlUser.equals("Save Record"))
                    {
                        ResultSet rs;

                        sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (name, ID, result, date, date2) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
                        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                        stmt.setString(1, textField.getText());
                        stmt.setInt(2, id);
                        stmt.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
                        stmt.setDate(4,date );
                        stmt.setDate(5,date2);
                        // OLD: rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                        // OLD: updateUI(rs);
                        stmt.executeUpdate();
                        updateUI(id,  textField.getText(),textField_2.getText(),date,date2 );
                        // OLD: con.commit();
                    }
        else if(sqlUser.equals("Save Update"))
                    {
                        ResultSet rs;
                        sql = "UPDATE table_name SET result = ? , date = ?, date2 = ? WHERE name = ? AND ID = ?";
                        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                        stmt.setString(4, textField.getText());
                        stmt.setInt(5, id);
                        stmt.setString(1, textField_2.getText());
                        stmt.setDate(2, date);
                        stmt.setDate(3, date2);
                        // OLD: rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                        // OLD: updateUI(rs);
                        stmt.executeUpdate();
                        updateUI(id,  textField.getText(),textField_2.getText(),date,date2 );
                        // OLD: con.commit();
                    }
    } catch (SQLException err)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,err.getMessage());
    }

The updateUI method is as follows:

    public void updateUI(int id, String name, String result, Date date, Date date2)
        {
            try
            {
                String strCDate = dateFormat.format(date);//rs.getDate("date"));
                String strLADate = dateFormat.format(date2);//rs.getDate("date2"));

                textField.setText(name);//rs.getString("name"));
                textField_1.setText(id+"");//Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID")));
                textField_2.setText(result);//rs.getString("result"));
                lblCalculationDate.setText("Date: " + strCDate);
                lblLastAccessDate.setText("Date2: " + strLADate);
            }
            catch(SQLException err)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,err.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would I get the name, ID, and result to display in the GUI if I dont have the result set? Will I have to do a `select` statement?

Comment: No need for select as you inserted already the required data so just pass them again to the updateUI

Comment: Thanks! I was confused as if I were to keep a similar updateUI but your code edit helped!

Answer (score 2):

For inserts & updates you should use

`stmt.execute();
rs = stmt.getResultSet();`

or

`stmt.executeUpdate();
rs = stmt.getResultSet();`

Additionally you don't need `con.commit()` since you are not setting `con.setAutoCommit(false)`

Unrelated side note: as a best practice you should avoid hard-coding SQL in java code

Comment: I get a null pointer exception but that probably because results sets and update/inserts dont work together (no result set when inserting/updating)

Comment: Correct...your SQL doesn't have anything being returned, hence the null pointer exception.  You should create a stored procedure which would first perform the insert/update, and then return whatever result is needed.  The other option would be to execute another SQL statement after the update/insert to retrieve the results desired.